# Run commands in new terminals, then kill later

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have a `start.bat` similar to the following:

```
start npx tailwindcss -i ./www/src/styles/main.css -o ./www/dist/styles/main.css --watch
start caddy run
```

It launches 2 new cmd prompts and starts processes within them (which both run indefinitely). Is there a way for this bat file to send a kill command to the cmds it spawned? Ideally I'd have a single command to kill all "child" processes which were created.

Comment: Out of curiosity is there a reason you need to use a batch file rather than a PowerShell script?

Comment: No, PS would be fine. I'm just more familiar with batch.

Comment: Do not name a batch file like a command, `start`, because you could unintentionally do cyclic calls otherwise…

Comment: As an aside: what you're spawning aren't _`cmd.exe`_ instances, unless the executables you're invoking (`npx`, `caddy`) happen to be implemented _as batch files_. Otherwise, the executables are launched directly, without involving a shell such as `cmd.exe`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
set "wintitle=my process %time%"
start "%wintitle%" npx tailwindcss -i ./www/src/styles/main.css -o ./www/dist/styles/main.css --watch
start "%wintitle%" caddy run

....

taskkill /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq %wintitle%"
```

[untested] - should work in theory...

Always best to `start` with a quoted-title as the first quoted string seen by the `start` command may be eaten and used as a title otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

A **PowerShell solution** - which is acceptable as both *implied* by this question's tagging and as *explicitly stated* by icanfathom (the OP) in a comment ("No, PS would be fine") - using the [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) and [`Stop-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/stop-process) cmdlets:

```
$processes = & {
  Start-Process -PassThru npx 'tailwindcss -i ./www/src/styles/main.css -o ./www/dist/styles/main.css --watch'
  Start-Process -PassThru caddy run
}

# ...

# Stop (kill) all launched processes.
$processes | Stop-Process
```